# Media Recorder Crash with logcat message "HwMemBitMask::~HwMemBitMask ************** FORCE FREEING!!!!! "

Tags: android, media, video-recording

I am using media recorder to record video with following code. Can any one explain why `HwMemBitMask::~HwMemBitMask ************** FORCE FREEING!!!!!` message is for ? It happens when method startRecording() code get executed.

```
public class VideoRecorder extends FragmentActivity implements  SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
  MediaRecorder recorder;
  SurfaceHolder holder;
  boolean           recording   = false;
  SurfaceView       cameraView;
  private Camera    mCamera;
  String filePath;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("filepath");

    initRecorder();
    setContentView(R.layout.videorecorder);
    cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.video_surface_view);
    holder = cameraView.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    cameraView.setClickable(true);

}

private void initRecorder()
{
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
    recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
}

private void prepareRecorder()
{
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    try
    {
        recorder.prepare();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
}



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    if(mCamera != null)
    {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    try
    {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    prepareRecorder();
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
{
    mCamera.startPreview();
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    if (recording)
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recording = false;
    }
    recorder.release();
    finish();
}

public void recordButtonClick(View view)
{
    Button recordButton = (Button)(view);
    if(recordButton.getText().toString().contains("Record"))
    {
        // Recording started
        findViewById(R.id.play_stop).setEnabled(false);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_done)).setText("Done");
        findViewById(R.id.cancel_done).setEnabled(false);
        startRecording();
        findViewById(R.id.blink_recording_text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recordButton.setText("Stop");
    }
    else
    {
        findViewById(R.id.blink_recording_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        stopRecording();
        findViewById(R.id.play_stop).setEnabled(true);
        findViewById(R.id.cancel_done).setEnabled(true);
        recordButton.setText("Record");
    }
}
public void playButtonClick(View v)
{

}
public void doneButtonClick(View v)
{

}
private void startRecording()
{

    if (recording)
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recording = false;

        // Let's initRecorder so we can record again
        initRecorder();
        prepareRecorder();
    }
    else
    {
        recording = true;
        recorder.start();
    }
}
private void stopRecording()
{
    if (recording)
    {
        recorder.stop();
        recording = false;

    }
}
}
```